# SQL Server Express Limitation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I would like to use Express instead of Standard. Does Express still have the annoying habit of going to sleep if left unused for a period of time?

Comment: Do you mean the AutoClose property of a database or is there some other kind of "going to sleep" you have in mind?

Comment: The SQL Express limitation kind. This post is quite recent so I guess its still there.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26168739/221683

Comment: SQL express does have lot of limitations as compared to Standard edition. One thing is gr8 for express its free and if it does your task you can stick to it

Comment: 10Gb a database, one CPU and a single GB of memory is plenty OK for me I think.

Comment: Memory is NOT LIMITED to just 1 G database engine instance can use more than 1 G starting from SQL Server 2012 express

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does't, and never did.

The post you link links to the blog [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlexpress/understanding-sql-express-behavior-idle-time-resource-usage-auto_close-and-user-instances) that explains that the 'instance going to sleep' is a **RANU** behavior (user instance), not an Express behavior. As you plan to move from Standard to Express, is obvious that that you do not plan to move to user instances (RANU).

Comment: Sounds good. I will give it a go.

Comment: link no longer works.